# Materializecss framework - error when converting scss file to css

Tags: css, sass, materialize

I'm trying to convert materialize scss to css. But I'm getting error:
/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.

I have visual studio code and installed sass `npm install -g sass`

then in terminal:
`sass materialize.scss output.css`

I'm trying to convert only some components. I want use materializecss with one page but css is in conflict.

What I got is this in output.css

````
/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
 *    ,
 * 27 | @import "components/table_of_contents";
 *    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *    '
 *   materialize.scss 27:9  root stylesheet */

body::before {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", "SF Mono", Monaco, Inconsolata, "Fira Mono",
      "Droid Sans Mono", monospace, monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  content: "Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.\a    \2577 \a 27 \2502  @import \"components/table_of_contents\";\a    \2502          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\a    \2575 \a   materialize.scss 27:9  root stylesheet";
} ```
````

Comment: use [live sass compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) instead.

Comment: Not sure how to set live sass compiler. But when I tried build in sass and some other I'm getting same error. This is what I got after compiling materialize.sass . '/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.'